# VBA - Trying to verify two columns and resizing when a value is missing in one

Tags: excel, vba

I have the need to find if let's say COL A have a value that's missing from COL B, i want to find if it's missing and then delete and shift up the rows, the thing is the structure looks like this

```
ID   | INFO1    | INFO2   | INFO3 ------------    ID2   | INFO1    | INFO2   | INFO3  
50   | XXXXX    | XXXXX   | XXXXX ------------    50    | XXXXX    | XXXXX   | XXXXX  
51   | XXXXX    | XXXXX   | XXXXX ------------    51    | XXXXX    | XXXXX   | XXXXX  
52   | XXXXX    | XXXXX   | XXXXX ------------    52    | XXXXX    | XXXXX   | XXXXX  
53   | XXXXX    | XXXXX   | XXXXX ------------    53    | XXXXX    | XXXXX   | XXXXX  
54   | XXXXX    | XXXXX   | XXXXX ------------    55    | XXXXX    | XXXXX   | XXXXX  
55   | XXXXX    | XXXXX   | XXXXX ------------    56    | XXXXX    | XXXXX   | XXXXX
```

And there begins my problem, so far I've managed this:

```
Sub Teste()
   Dim rngA As Range
   Set rngA = Range("F2")
   Set rngB = Range("H2")
   While rngA.Value <> ""
        Columns("H:H").Select
        Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:=rngA.Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Cell Is Nothing Then
            rngA.Value = ""
            Set rngA = rngA.Offset(1)
        Else
            Set rngA = rngA.Offset(1)
        End If
    Wend
    While rngB.Value <> ""
        Columns("F:F").Select
        Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:=rngB.Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Cell Is Nothing Then
            rngB.Value = ""
            Set rngB = rngB.Offset(1)
        Else
            Set rngB = rngB.Offset(1)
        End If
    Wend

End Sub
```

This manage to find what value from ID is missing on ID2 and substitute it with an empty value, but I want to delete the missing ID | INFO1 | INFO2| INFO3 delete them and shift the rows up, and for the life of me I can't find how to do it. (The code don't reflect the example)

Does somebody have an idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You example doesn't exactly match the code -- looks like you want to delete the ID column and three columns to the right (so the ID columns are for columns apart), but in your code the ID columns are F and H.  For my code below, I'm assuming that you want to delete F-G and H-I.

```
Dim searchColumn As Range
Dim rngA As Range

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 2
    If i = 1 Then
        Set rngA = Range("f2")
        Set searchColumn = Range("h:h")
    Else
        Set rngA = Range("h2")
        Set searchColumn = Range("f:f")
    End If
    While rngA.Value <> ""
        searchColumn.Select
        Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:=rngA.Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
        If Cell Is Nothing Then
            Set rngA = rngA.Offset(1)
            Range(rngA.Offset(-1), rngA.Offset(-1, 1)).Delete xlUp
        Else
            Set rngA = rngA.Offset(1)
        End If
    Wend
Next
```

If you need to delete additional columns, change the line with `.Delete` -- the `1` in that line represents the number of columns to the right of the ID column to delete.

Comment: Thank you, altering the code slightly to match my case and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  If my answer helped, please consider marking it as Accepted.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, kinda new to using StackOverflow.